# Does the number of seconds go out of boundaries of some limit which then give some wacky numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok here's the page http://unurbandictionary.comule.com/stats.php
The 8th line (also the very last line just before the chart graph) reports "average time between hits/visits (longer than a minute) 868.65 day(s)"
I know this is wrong because my site haven't been online for that long.
The query to calculate that number is

```
$sql = "SELECT CAST((avg(difference)/86400) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as average 
    FROM
             (SELECT remote_addr,hit,nexthit,nexthit - hit as difference
              FROM
                  (SELECT p1.remote_addr,p1.inserted_at as hit,
                          (SELECT MIN(inserted_at)
                           FROM page_view p2
                           WHERE p2.remote_addr = p1.remote_addr
                           AND p2.inserted_at > p1.inserted_at)
                           as nexthit
                  FROM page_view p1
                  )T1
              WHERE nexthit IS NOT NULL
              AND nexthit - hit >= 60
             )T2
       ";
```

86400 is number of seconds there are in 1 day.
`inserted_at` column is of type `datetime`
I would've sqlFiddle.com my data if i could but it's got more than 8000 characters.

My question is why such a huge number of days? does the difference of (nexthit - hit) become out of wack (go out of some sort of boundary or limit) if it's longer than a certain number of days and throw everything off? And if so, what can i do to solve this issue?

Also last week some time this number was 5 point something odd days which made sense.

UPDATE: this is what i change the query to using combination of `TO_DAYS()` and `TIME_TO_SEC()`

```
$sql = "SELECT CAST((avg(difference)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as average 
  FROM
  (SELECT remote_addr,hit,nexthit,((TO_DAYS(nexthit)+(TIME_TO_SEC(nexthit)/86400) )
                                  -(TO_DAYS(hit)+(TIME_TO_SEC(hit)/86400))) as difference
   FROM

     (SELECT p1.remote_addr,p1.inserted_at as hit,
        (SELECT MIN(inserted_at)
         FROM page_view p2
         WHERE p2.remote_addr = p1.remote_addr
         AND p2.inserted_at > p1.inserted_at)
        as nexthit
     FROM page_view p1
     )T1
   )T2
   WHERE nexthit IS NOT NULL
   AND difference >= (3600/86400)
       ";
```

I changed the stats to report within a minute, within the hour, and this query is for the ones that are longer than 1 hour.
As i don't trust the result of time2 - time1 anymore look at this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28428/2) not sure what those numbers represent, neither seconds or days.

Comment: Just remove the `/86400` and you'll be fine.

Comment: but that will give number of seconds, i want it to be days. as these hits are 60 seconds or longer

Comment: Whenever you subtract two time values, the difference is given in days itself, that's the unit. Even though the difference is in seconds, it is showed as fraction of a day. Furthermore, modify your condition to `AND nexthit - hit > 60/86400`. That would be the right thing here.

Comment: what? not according to this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28403/0 a number which is not really seconds either! I am confused now

Comment: i have changed the code like you said and now it's showing a huge number, check the page and see.

Comment: I am thinking i might have to use a combination of TO_DAYS() and TIME_TO_SEC() to get some sort of decent number.

Comment: Yes, that's a great choice.

Comment: I just edited the same fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4ddd/7 and found that the TIME_TO_SEC() function works perfect.

Comment: why is the last row NULL in this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4ddd/9/0 but the result is correct in this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4ddd/10/0 I don't think you can use TIME_TO_SEC(time2-time1) you'll have to use TIME_TO_SEC(time2) - TIME_TO_SEC(time1). The difference of time is just weird.

Comment: On both of those fiddles, you have the second set of dates set to the year 2103. However, even after correcting the date, the problem still remains. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8c7f/1). Scroll down and notice those results where the difference is 50 to 59. You might be interested in the function TIMESTAMPDIFF, as demonstrated in [this other fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ee93/8). This function is MySQL 5.0+.

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF seems to do everything correct, I ended up using combination of TO_DAYS() and TIME_TO_SEC() but i never use the subtraction 2 times values since that always gives strange values